# Affirmative vs negative sentence with "mica"

Tags: adverbs

I have heard the following two sentences in a discussion between a wife and a husband about the husband's addiction to smoking, in a TV series:

> – Non ce la fai proprio a smettere, vero? (= You just can't quit, can you?)
>   –  Così però mica mi aiuti! (= That doesn't help at all!)

I see that "mica" is an informal equivalent of "affatto" (= at all), but I don't understand why the Italian sentence is not in the negative as the English one. Does "però" make that sentence negative?

Comment: Related question: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1656.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***[Mica](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/mica_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/):***

> L’avverbio di negazione mica ha la funzione di rafforzare la negazione della frase. È tipico dell’uso parlato e informale ed è quindi sconsigliabile nello scritto.
>
> Come per gli altri aggettivi e pronomi indefiniti negativi, richiede la doppia negazione quando si trova dopo il verbo
>
> - *Non sono mica stupido*
>
> non quando lo precede
>
> - *Mica sono stupido.*

(Treccani.it)

As you can see from the above examples when the adverb “mica” precedes the verb you don’t use the double negative construction.

As per your example:

> Così però *mica mi aiuti*.

Comment: It should be noted (from Treccani's dictionary - http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mica1/) that _mica_ means literally "_crumb_", to mean a very small quantity of something or the smallest/infinitesimal quantity possible.
So "Mica sono stupido" could literally mean "I am not stupid, not even a crumb" or "I don't have even a crumb of stupidity". A similar expression is _per niente_ (Non sono _per niente_ stupido, Così non mi aiuti _per niente_ , etc.)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi - probably “in the least” is the English expression that comes close in usage and meaning. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-least

Comment: that's a good one. I would add that to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The word *mica* was originally a noun that means [*breadcrumbs*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mica1), intended as something insignificant.

Now that this word acts as an adverb can be used both as a replacement or an intensifier of the negation *non*. The following sentences have the same meaning:

> Così mica mi aiuti
>
> Così non mi aiuti mica